# SQL Server 2014 sum based on previous record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following 3 columns.  Col3 first value is always 0.  The values after that is always going to be the sum of col2 + col3 of the previous record.

```
col1  col2   col3
1     6.48   0
2     1.95
3     1.66
4     .84
5     .56
6     1.24
```

So the final values would be as follows:

```
col1  col2     col3
   1     6.48    0
   2     1.95    6.48
   3     1.66    8.43
   4     .84    10.09
   5     .56    10.93
   6     1.24   11.49
```

Does anyone know if this can be done without a cursor in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use windowed `SUM` and subtract current value:

```
SELECT *, SUM(col2) OVER(ORDER BY col1)-col2 AS col3
FROM tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25bb398a00a7ace22eb7d4505fe30e65)**